# Using router-outlet in a shared module component?

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I'm trying to standardize the UX of my feature modules by sharing a common sidebar in all of them. Right now I'm using grids in Bootstrap5 and a router-outlet in some grid elements to keep things nice and standardized. As long as I don't go into a child route within the lazy feature modules it works great.

- `/corepages` works
- `/lazy1`     works
- `/lazy/anything` fails

And how it fails is that all my core/app assets get /lazy1 added to their uri.  For example my img assets are at `/assets/img/pic.jpg` but when loading into a lazy loaded module the page goes white and ALL assets (including the js bundle) change into 404 with new uris like `/lazy1/assets/img/pic.jpg`.

I'd really prefer not to pull the standardized markup from the shared components. It's so nice just slapping content into the components/pages and letting the shell route wrap them in a pre-formatted space.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to run in to this bizarre issue you should add a base tag to your index.html:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <base href="/" > <!-- this fixed it -->
```